# How to show transfer integral is a real number?

Tags: condensed-matter, approximations, tight-binding

I want to know how to show transfer integral is a real number.

I am learning tight binding approach.

Now let's consider the two-dimensional system whose unit cell has two atoms (for example, hexagonal lattice).
According to the tight binding approach, the wave function is given as

$\Phi_A({\bf k,r})=\sum_{{{\bf R}_A}} e^{i {\bf k}\cdot {\bf R}_A}\phi_A({\bf r-R}_A)$

$\Phi_B({\bf k,r})=\sum_{{{\bf R}_B}} e^{i {\bf k}\cdot {\bf R}_B}\phi_B({\bf r-R}_B)$

And the Hamiltonian of this has four elements. $<\Phi_A|H|\Phi_A>,<\Phi_A|H|\Phi_B>,<\Phi_B|H|\Phi_A>,<\Phi_B|H|\Phi_B>$

$<\Phi_A|H|\Phi_B>$

$= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{R_A} \sum_{R_B} e^{i{\bf k}\cdot({\bf R}_A-{\bf R}_B)}<\phi_A({\bf r-R})|H|\phi_B({\bf r-R}_B)>$

$= \sum_{\Delta R} e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf \Delta R}_A}<\phi_A({\bf r-\Delta R})|H|\phi_B({\bf r})>$

$=t f({\bf k})$

I defined $\Delta {\bf R}={\bf R}_A-{\bf R}_B$ and changed of variables.

My question is how to prove the transfer integral $t$ is the real number.

Comment: Well, naively I would just check that $t^*=t$.

Comment: I tried.

$t^*=<\phi_{A}(r-R)|H|\phi_{B}(r)>^*=<\phi_{B}(r)|H|\phi_{A}(r-R)>$

What to do next??